# Messages leaderboard issue discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

How are you?

I'm coding a Discord bot and I'm making a message leaderboard command, which displays up to 15 members with most messages (quick.db package to store data). Basically, It's alright when I run the code, but when someone who has so much messages and should appear in the leaderboard leave the server, it returns an error when I try to get the members tag and undefined in the message.

Is it possible to hide the user or delete them from the database?

What have I tried to solve the problem?

I tried to read Discord docs. and quick.db package to see if I can delete the user when they leave (using guildMemberRemove event), but what if they get back to the server?
ﾠ

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to delete user(lefted)* data from database once user left the server in [guildMemberRemove](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberRemove) event

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help! I could fix the issue partially, but look what happens when I try to get user tag or username: [link](https://imgur.com/a/Wxzwr80)

Comment: sorry for that first one is better way ig i'll update answer.